# How can I get accurate totals from a subform when in splitform view, currently each record needs to be selected before the total is correct

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am setting up a system for the reconciliation process of accounts payable.  I set up a few tables for inputting the groups of tickets that we get every day to log them before we get in the invoices.

I have a handful of tables that provide information about some of the fields in the tables but the key tables are:

Ticket_Group:

- TGID(autonumber)
- Ticket_Date
- SupplierID(Unique Identifier for Raw Material Provider)
- ShipperID(Unique Identifier for Shipping Company of classification)
- MaterialID(Unique Identifier for material)
- gl_dep(general ledger department)
- mat_inv_rec(true/false if material invoice has been received)
- freight_inv_rec(true/false if freight invoice has been received)

Ticket:

- TID(Autonumber for Each Ticket)
- TGID(Links to TGID in Ticket_Group, Many TID to One TGID)
- qty(Quantity of Material)

What I want to be able to do is see all of the Records from Ticket_Group that still have their invoices not received.  But I also need to see the totals so I can match them correctly.  Not exactly the ideal way to do AP reconciliation but it is much better than how we currently do it(pseudo-pivot table with supplier and shipper combinations along one side and days of the month along the top and individual tickets as values being added together in each cell).

What I have now is a splitform of the Ticket_Group table with the Ticket subform.  I put a sum([qty]) in the footer of the subform and referenced that field in the mainform.  This only half works because the total is right in the single form view but the datasheet view displays the selected records total as the total for all records until each individual record has been selected.

I thought maybe an onload event for the form that cycled through every record might work, but I figured there must be a better way.

I am super new with MS Access so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Not quite understanding the issue. The total is right in single form view of which form? Perhaps you could provide an image?

Comment: @June7, I guess mainform is in datasheet view what puts subform data in a treeview.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Subform-Field can't work because it refers to the actual (selected) record of the mainform. 
That's why the Datasheet-View shows the value of the actual selected record of mainform for all records, because there is only one subform with the caclulated field that changes depending on the mainforms record, not a new one for every record of the mainform.

To get the value in the Datasheet-View get it from the tables, not the subform.

E.g. set the `Control-Source`of a TextBpx to:

```
=DSum("qty","Ticket","TGID = " & Ticket_Group.TGID)
```

or add the expression to your`Form.RecordSource`as a field like:

```
Select Ticket_Group.TGID, Ticket_Group.Ticket_Date, ... , DSum("qty","Ticket","TGID = " & Ticket_Group.TGID) as SumQty FROM Ticket_Group
```

to have the form editable.

Or join

```
Select TGID, Sum(qty) As SumTicketQty FROM Ticket Group By TGID
```

with your mainform's query and then bind it to the mainform, but that leads to a readonly query.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  I think I am doing something wrong but I can create the query but when I try to add it to my form it isn't an option on the add fields tab.  When I try to create a new form to see if I just needed to have the query as part of the record source.  But it looks like it only shows up as a subform.  And unfortunately I need to be able to see the value on the datasheet portion of the splitform.  Would it maybe be better to make a query for all of the information I need for the main form?  I am concerned the recordset would not be updateable through that method.